# VHDL Getting a simulation fatal error in the loading design in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim

(Yes I know there's an easier way, yes my professor is asking for the long way.)
The following is the code for my 1 bit adder/subtractor.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FA1Bit is
    port(x,y,Cin: in std_logic;
         op: in std_logic;
         S, Cout: out std_logic);
end FA1Bit;

architecture FA1Bit_arch of FA1Bit is

begin
    behavior : PROCESS(op,x,y,Cin)
    begin
    if op = '0' then --if we're adding the bits;
        if Cin = '0' then
            if x = y then
                S <= '0';
                if (x= '1' and y = '1') then
                    Cout <= '1';
                else --if x = 0 and y = 0;
                    Cout <= '0';
                end if;
            else --if x not equal to y;
                S <= '1';
                Cout <= '0';
            end if;
        else --if Cin = 1 then;
            if x = y then
                S <= '1';
                if (x= '1' and y = '1') then
                    Cout <= '1';
                else --if x = 0 and y = 0;
                    Cout <= '0';
                end if;
            else --if x not equal to y;
                S <= '0';
                Cout <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;

    else -- if we're subtracting bits (op = 1);
        if Cin = '0' then
            if x = y then
                Cout <= '0';
                S <= '0';
            elsif (x ='1' and y = '0') then
                Cout <= '0';
                S <= '1';
            else --if x not equal to y;
                S <= '1';
                Cout <= '1';
            end if;
        else --if Cin = 1 then;
            if x = y then
                Cout <= '1';
                S <= '1';
            elsif (x ='1' and y = '0') then
                Cout <= '0';
                S <= '0';
            else --if x not equal to y;
                S <= '0';
                Cout <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    end PROCESS;

end FA1Bit_arch;
```

Now I use this component in my 4 bit adder/subtractor in this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
entity FA4Bit is
port (
X : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
Y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
C0: in STD_LOGIC;
S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
C4: out STD_LOGIC;
OP1: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
end FA4Bit;

architecture FA4Bit_arch of FA4Bit is
component FA1bit
port ( X: in STD_LOGIC; Y: in STD_LOGIC; CIN : in STD_LOGIC;
SI : out STD_LOGIC; COUT: out STD_LOGIC;
OPA : in STD_LOGIC);
end component;
signal C : std_logic_vector(1 to 3);
begin
U1: FA1bit port map (X=>X(0), Y=>Y(0), CIN=> C0, SI=>S(0), COUT=>C(1), OPA => OP1(0));
U2: FA1bit port map (X=>X(1), Y=>Y(1), CIN=> C(1), SI=>S(1), COUT=>C(2), OPA => OP1(1));
U3: FA1bit port map (X=>X(2), Y=>Y(2), CIN=> C(2), SI=>S(2), COUT=>C(3), OPA => OP1(2));
U4: FA1bit port map (X=>X(3), Y=>Y(3), CIN=> C(3), SI=>S(3), COUT=>C4, OPA => OP1(3));

end FA4Bit_arch;
```

Everything compiles perfectly same goes for the following testbench.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FA4Bit_tb is
end ;
architecture arch of FA4Bit_tb is
component FA4Bit
    port ( X1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Y : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    C0 : in std_logic;
    S : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    C4 : out std_logic;
    OP1: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end component;

signal X : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal Y : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal C0 : std_logic := '0';
signal opa: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
signal S : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal C4 : std_logic;

begin
    UUT : FA4Bit
    port map (X1 => X, Y => Y, C0 => C0, S => S, C4 => C4, OP1=> opa);

X <= not X after 5 ns;
Y <= not Y after 7 ns; 
opa <= not opa after 9 ns;

end arch;
```

However, I'm receiving a FATAL ERROR in the loading design.

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3817) Port "X" of entity "fa4bit" is not in the component being instantiated.
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /fa4bit_tb/UUT File: C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/320 PROJECT 3ANJAD HAL MARRA/FA4Bit.vhd Line: 5
# FATAL ERROR while loading design
# Error loading design
```

Comment: It's right, you're not allowed to rename ports in the component, X1, differently than in the entity X!

Comment: Why does each 1 bit adder/subtractor have an individualized op value?  A single opa bit can direct a 4 bit adder/subtractor. All three entity and architecture pairs appear to be written in different styles. Consistent style (white space, lines, indentation, parentheses around conditions and capitalization) can help errors stand out. Generic and port clauses can be copied from entity declarations to component declarations or vice versa (bottom up versus top down).

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason why I hate component instantiations. In your component instantiation, the port is called `X1`, not `X`. Renaming to `X` should fix this issue. Then you have a couple of similar ones to fix (`OP` and `S` on `FA1bit`).

If you use entity instantiations, then a lot of problems like this go away.

Comment: I'm still a beginner, I would like to know more about the difference between the two types of instantiations, can you link me? Many thanks.

Comment: Look up direct instantiation. Since vhdl 93 you can directly instantiate an entity from a library.  You only need components for verilog code or net lists. The advantage is that it's a syntax error when you have a problem like yours,  not a mapping error. In synthesis or big simulations,  syntax error is found in seconds,  mapping may take several minutes.

Comment: A component instantiation with the reserved word `entity` (there is no mention of direct instantiation in the standard) only reduces the chance of a typo by 1 in 3. You can also copy the port of the entity in question to the component declaration. There are various tools for creating component declarations and component instantiation generic and port map aspects from entity declarations, some editor VHDL packages included.  You have of getting signal port names wrong in architectures and some editor packages watch out for that too. Component declarations enable configuration specifications.

Comment: @Tricky you can actually instantiate Verilog modules directly, just need to explicitly compile the file on a library, which in modelsim iirc is not mandatory for Verilog.

Comment: I very much disagree that an entity instantiation only reduces the chance of a typo by 1 in 3. In my experience, the value is much, much higher than this. Tedious copy-pasting in multiple places is very error prone when updated and maintained by a human. And it's not just typos - forgetting to compile a specific file (also a common human error) leads to similar issues. But what's worse is that (as @Tricky points out) a human error with a component instantiation will tend to waste hours, not seconds. Therefore, the overall risk is much higher.

Comment: @O.Sinno _Direct instantiation_ was introduced in 1993. Meanwhile, over in the [Verilog] tag, there will be a zillion questions from university students who are still being taught a Verilog coding style that was superceded in 2001. Do these university professors _ever_ update their course material?