# Ripple carry adder in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, test-bench

hi i' trying to do a 4 bit ripple carry adder with VHDL. The problem is that i'm trying to do a testbench to simulate it in ModelSim, but it doesn't work. This is the code and also the code reported by ModelSim:

Full adder code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity fullAdder is
    port( -- Input of the full-adder
            a   : in std_logic;
            -- Input of the full-adder
            b   : in std_logic;
            -- Carry input 
            c_i : in std_logic;
            -- Output of the full-adder
            o   : out std_logic;
            -- Carry output
            c_o : out std_logic
        );
end fullAdder;
architecture data_flow of fullAdder is

 begin

  o   <= a xor b xor c_i;
  
  c_o <= (a and b) or (b and c_i) or (c_i and a);

  end data_flow;
```

Ripple carry adder code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


 entity Ripple_Carry_Adder is 
 Port (
  A: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
  B:in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
  Cin:in std_logic;
  S:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  Cout:out std_logic
 );
 end Ripple_Carry_Adder;

 architecture data_flow2 of Ripple_Carry_Adder is 
 component fullAdder
 Port(
 A:in std_logic;
 B:in std_logic;
 Cin:in std_logic;
 S:out std_logic;
 Cout:out std_logic
 );
 end component;
 signal c1,c2,c3:STD_LOGIC;
 begin
 FA1:fullAdder port map(A(0),B(0), Cin, S(0), c1);
 FA2:fullAdder port map(A(1),B(1), c1, S(1), c2);
 FA3:fullAdder port map(A(2),B(2), c2, S(2), c3);
 FA4:fullAdder port map(A(3),B(3), c3, S(3), Cout);
 end data_flow2;
```

code of Ripple carry adder testbench:

```
            library IEEE;
            use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
            use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
            use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
            ENTITY ripple_carry_adder_tb is
            end ripple_carry_adder_tb;

            ARCHITECTURE behavior OF ripple_carry_adder_tb is
                constant T_CLK   : time := 10 ns; -- Clock period
                constant T_RESET : time := 25 ns; -- Period before the reset deassertion
                COMPONENT Ripple_Carry_Adder
                    PORT (
                        A:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                        B:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                        Cin:in std_logic;
                        S:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                        Cout:out std_logic
                    );
                END COMPONENT;
                
                signal A_tb:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
                signal B_tb:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
                signal Cin_tb:std_logic:='0';
                signal S_tb:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                signal Cout_tb:std_logic;
                
                signal clk_tb : std_logic := '0'; -- clock signal, intialized to '0' 
                signal rst_tb  : std_logic := '0'; -- reset signal  
                signal end_sim : std_logic := '1';
                
                BEGIN
                    clk_tb <= (not(clk_tb) and end_sim) after T_CLK / 2;  -- The clock toggles after T_CLK / 2 when end_sim is high. When end_sim is forced low, the clock stops toggling and the simulation ends.
                    rst_tb <= '1' after T_RESET;
                    RP_1: Ripple_Carry_Adder PORT MAP(A=>A_tb,B=>B_tb,Cin=>Cin_tb,S=>S_tb,Cout=>Cout_tb);
                d_process: process(clk_tb, rst_tb) -- process used to make the testbench signals change synchronously with the rising edge of the clock
                    variable t : integer := 0; -- variable used to count the clock cycle after the reset
                  begin
                    if(rst_tb = '0') then
                      A_tb  <= "0000";
                      B_tb  <= "0000";
                      Cin_tb<='0';
                      t := 0;
                    elsif(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
                      A_tb<=A_tb+1;
                      B_tb<=B_tb+1;
                      t := t + 1;
                      if (t>32) then
                        end_sim <= '0';
                      end if;
                    end if;
                  end process;
            END;
```

and this is errors reported by ModelSim when i trying to start simulation:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3817) Port "c_i" of entity "fulladder" is not in the component being instantiated.
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /ripple_carry_adder_tb/RP_1/FA1 File: 
C:/Users/utente/Desktop/full_adder.vhd Line: 11
# FATAL ERROR while loading design
# Error loading design
```

Why doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: Your component of `FullAdder` has ports `Cin` and `Cout`, but the actual entity has `c_i` and `c_o`, hence the component missmatches the entity and mapping fails. You need to fix the port names, or use direct instantiation and remove components.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.3.3 Default binding indication "The default binding indication includes a default port map aspect if the design entity implied by the entity aspect contains formal ports. The default port map aspect associates each local port in the corresponding component instantiation (if any) with a formal of the same simple name. **It is an error** if such a formal does not exist or if its mode and type are not appropriate for such an association. ...", See 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL Getting a simulation fatal error in the loading design in modelsim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078264/vhdl-getting-a-simulation-fatal-error-in-the-loading-design-in-modelsim)